# Using Pulumi and Github actions to spin up GCP Postgres Instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, pulumi

I am trying to spin up a gcp postgres instance using Pulumi and Gituhub actions.
The pulumi code:

```
myinstance = sql.DatabaseInstance(
    "backoffice-instance",
    database_version="POSTGRES_15",
    settings=sql.DatabaseInstanceSettingsArgs(
        tier="db-custom-2-4096",
        activation_policy="ALWAYS",
        availability_type="ZONAL",
        ip_configuration=sql.DatabaseInstanceSettingsIpConfigurationArgs(
            authorized_networks=[
                sql.DatabaseInstanceSettingsIpConfigurationAuthorizedNetworkArgs(
                    value="0.0.0.0/0"
                )
            ]
        ),
        backup_configuration={
            "enabled": True,
            "point_in_time_recovery_enabled": True,
        },
    ),
    deletion_protection=False,
)
```

I would like to add the github actions CIDR to Pulumi code.I suppose that I will need to query meta https://api.github.com/meta , add it as env variable and use it in pulumi.
But it seems very complex. Is there other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a python curl command to retrieve the CIDR from the API you shared, save the values in a list and add it as an input for `authorized_networks`.

Comment: You might want to elaborate your proposal.

Comment: Basically would be

- Create a small python curl using the request library to retrieve all of the IPs from the endpoint that its mentioned above
- Save the output of those IPs into a variable or a list
- And then iterate over each repetition of those IPs and add it as an input of the `value` field on the `DatabaseInstanceSettingsIpConfigurationAuthorizedNetworkArgs` parameter.

Now writing this I can see that it might need to be tweaked or re executed every now and then in case github changes its IPs

Comment: Are you aware that you can [edit] to improve your answer according to [answer].

Comment: @Yunnosch Hi there. No I wasn't aware of that. I'll take note of that for further posts. Thanks.

Comment: So you refuse to use that new found [edit]ing ability to improve this answer post and put the additional information and maybe a code version of your proposal into it? You could even go so far as to actually follow [answer]. Why not?